# need to creat variable variable in Javascript--not an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm needing to call a plugin that uses a var to work it's self.  but I can't get the var cause that can change so... this is what I was trying to do.

```
var selection = $(".view-your-rescues .cms_textarea,.post-a-rescue .cms_textarea,.edit-account-details .cms_textarea");

if(selection.length > 0 ) {
    selection
        .css({"height":"100","width":"500"})
        .each(function(i) { 
            var eval("hb"+i ) = $(this).htmlbox({
                toolbars:[[
                    "separator","bold","italic","underline","strike","sup","sub",
                    "separator","justify","left","center","right",
                    "separator","ol","ul","indent","outdent"
                ]],
                icons:"silk",
                skin:"red",
                idir:"/uploads/htmlbox/",
                about:false
        });
    });
}
```

So that is based on this http://htmlbox.remiya.com/cms/demo/iconsets-demo/ where you'll see that that in order to do two you need to have the different vars.

The important part is

```
.each(function(i){ 
    var eval("hb"+i )= $(this).htmlbox({
```

I tried the eval.. but I don't like that idea and it don't work anyway... any ideas?

EDIT: I can't do  var eval("hb"+i )= $(this) and if I go

eval("hb"+i )= $(this)

I just get "hb0 is not defined"

Hope that makes sense.  Thank you for the help.
Cheers -Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `var` there won't help much at all -- even if it worked, it'd put the variables out of any useful scope in this case.

Globals are actually usually members of `window`, so what you could do, if you're ok with globals, is something like

```
.each(function(i) { 
    window["hb"+i] = $(this).htmlbox({ /* your params */ }); 
});
```

Comment: that seems to work.. didn't get it working as this is the error.. 

global_hb.jqhb_0.cmd is not a function
[Break On This Error] global_hb.jqhb_0.cmd("bold"); 

which means it works but the plugin don't understand.. :/ tk for the help.. other ideas?

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with the variables you're making here?  As in, trying to trigger stuff in the boxes?

Comment: it looks like the plugin does just that.. thou I'm not sure how.. if you look in the link to the demo you'll see 2 of them editors working.. but in the code it's two vars... one for each.. I'd do that but there are pages it'll change in number.. so .. ??? lol

Comment: ok.. so I switched to 

window["hb_test__"+i] = $(this).attr("id","hb_test__"+i).htmlbox({ });

and it seems to work now... I'm still not sure where the var comes in but what I needed to do was add the an id on the fly.. tk for the help.. window[] is how and either it's needed.. who cares lol...

Comment: `window["example"] = "This is now pretty much a 'global'"; alert(example);`

Comment: yeah that part I got.. I wasn't understanding what how it was knowing what the var was.. I didn't have time to look or test more as it's working and I had to move on.. but since the root of the issue was the id, and the id don't need to match the var, I was left thinking that the var was a waste of memory.  That thought is due to not knowing if you can see what var your in or coming from.